# Can you double up on car payment?

Tags: savings

If I get a $15000 car loan and have 11.99% and a 60 month  term but pay double each month is that the same as getting a 30 month term?

Comment: It depends on the conditions of the loan: what happens if you pay double? Please add that info as well as your pountry.

Comment: Maybe you aren't in the US and maybe you just used it as an example, but 11.99% is a horrible rate for a car loan today.

Answer (score 6):

If the loan doesn't have a pre-payment penalty, then the typical loan doesn't require a doubling of the monthly payment to cut the loan period in half.

while it would seem that the doubling the payment would cut the term in half, in fact the additional money when it lowers the balace quicker also saves reduces the amount of interst paid each month.

I used the pmt and bper functions in excel. to calculate the following.

Original monthly payment given the stated 11.99% interest for 60 months for a 15K loan

```
=PMT(11.99/1200,60,15000) or -333.59 a month; 
Those 60 months will cost you $5,015.45 in interest (payment*60-15000)
```

To know what the new term would be if the payment was doubled to -667.18

```
=NPER(11.99/1200,-667.18,15000) or 25.59 months; 
this payment schedule will cost you $2,073.77 in interest. (payment*25.59 -15000)
```

to get the period to 30 months the payment will be:

```
=PMT(11.99/1200,30,15000) or -581.15 per month;
which will cost you in interest $2,434.53 (payment*30-15000)
```

So doubling the payment will save you the most interest and cut the term of the loan more than in half.

If you know have the ability to significantly increase the payment, you might look into refinancing the loan, because the bank frequently charges a lower interest rate for a shorter loan.

For example if the bank only charges 9% for a 36 month loan. The the payment for that loan is only $477 per month with $2,171.86 in interest.

But if you go back to the $581.15 per month you could afford in the earlier scenario, you could pay it off in 28.79 months at a total interest cost of $1,733.90

Comment: Do car loan work the same as mortgages? Where an early partial principal payment must be accepted and applied properly? Or can it just note that money received early goes towards the next month's payment, with no adjustment to amortization? I've never had car loan, no idea how they are written.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - In the US, there's no standard, it's up to the bank. Some allow you to designate what the extra money goes towards (in which case you should choose principal). Some limit you to only being "allowed" to prepay a certain number of months (and may even return payment once you're that far ahead). Some will let you pay, but then charge you a penalty. It really pays to sit down with a loan agent at your FI and understand how a particular loan works.